# Difference of computing binary search mid from left or right?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

What is the difference in calculating the mid position between these two calculations?

```
int mid = left + (right - left) / 2
```

and

```
int mid = right - (right - left) / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

There is **no significant difference**. Run it through some example numbers and see yourself.

The only difference is how it breaks the ties on **even numbers**, where the mid is then either one to the left or one to the right.

This occurs because most programming languages, when dividing two `int`s, will truncate the result. I.e. `3 / 2` is `1`, not `1.5`.

### Even Example

Example, suppose you have an array with `8` numbers (even). Then, the mid will either be on index `3` or `4`, both are valid.

[image: even]

The first option:

```java
int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
int mid = 0 + (7 - 0) / 2;
int mid = 7 / 2; // 3.5 before truncating
int mid = 3;
```

The second option:

```java
int mid = right - (right - left) / 2;
int mid = 7 - (7 - 0) / 2;
int mid = 7 - 7 / 2;
int mid = 7 - 3;
int mid = 4;
```

### Odd Example

For odd amounts, they both compute the same number:

```java
0 + (8 - 0) / 2 = 4
8 - (8 - 0) / 2 = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

`(right-left)/2` rounds downwards when `right-left` is odd, so

`int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;` rounds downward and

`int mid = right - (right - left) / 2;` rounds upward.

It might seem like they would both work fine, because `mid` ends up about half-way between `left` and `right` in either case, but actually the difference is very important, because the different rounding directions provide different critical guarantees:

Given that `left < right`:

- `mid = left + (right - left) / 2` is *guaranteed* to be less than `right`, but you might have `mid == left`; and
- `mid = right - (right - left) / 2` is *guaranteed* to be greater than `left`, but you might have `mid == right`.

In many types of binary search, deciding which guarantee you need is important for preventing infinite loops.

Since you need `left` or `right` to be different each iteration, after the decision, in the first case you can set `right = mid` or `left = mid+1`.  In the second case, you can set `right = mid-1` or `left = mid`.

Which pair of these you need depends on the type of condition you have when you're not using a 3-way compare.  You generally have an "is it high enough" test, or an "is it too high" test, and you need to set:

- `left = mid` when mid is not too high
- `left = mid+1` when mid not high enough
- `right = mid` when mid is high enough
- `right = mid-1` when mid is too high

For example, lets say you want to use binary search to find the highest positive `x` such that `x*(x+5) <= target`.  In this case, the condition tells us a test value `x` is either too high or not too high.  That means we will need to set `left = mid` or `right = mid-1` after the test.  That means that we need to round *up* when calculating `mid`:

```
while(left < right) {
    mid = right - (right-left)/2;
    if (mid*(mid+5) <= target) {
        // not too high
        left = mid; // left guaranteed to increase and be <= right
    } else {
        // too high
        right = mid-1; //right guaranteed to decrease and be >= left
    }
}
// now guaranteed that left == right
// return whichever one you like
return left;
```